# Problema con layout, imagen estático y textview

Tags: android

He creado una app de noticias, casi la tengo lista, pero hay un problema que no puedo solucionar con un layout del detalle de noticias, debe ser algo simple.

El Layout es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coninfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbardetalle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/noticiaimagendetalle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titulodetalle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TITULO"
        android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfechadetalle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titulodetalle"
        android:text="Fecha"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descripciondetalle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margen_estandar"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textfechadetalle"
        android:text="descripcion"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fuentedetalle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margen_estandar"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:text="fuente"
        android:textColor="@color/navigationBarColor"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Pero al probar y desplazar para arriba, solo se mueve el texto con scroll del textview `descripciondetalle`, pero la Imagen, Titulo, Fecha se queda fijos.

¿Alguna idea del problema?

Comment: Agrega completamente tu layout...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El primer contenedor debería de ser un ScrollView , y recuerda que solo puede tener un único hijo así que deberias agrupar todos los elementos en un RelativeLayout o LinearLayout como quieras.

```
 <ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // elementos aquí
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar ScrollView, si los elementos que agregues dentro quedan fuera de la pantalla visible, se generará un scroll.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    .... todos los controles que quieras que tengan scroll ...

</ScrollView>
```

Saludos.